# Retrieving the path of a file opened to construct an xarray Dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-xarray, netcdf4

If I open a dataset in `xarray` via

```
import xarray as xr

f = '/path/to/file.nc'
dset = xr.open_dataset(f)
```

Is there any way to later retrieve the source file location `/path/to/file.nc` from the object `dset`, say in a scope where `f` is no longer defined?

I could of course manually add an attribute to the `dset` object to carry this information, if it doesn't exist currently. For my purposes, that would be a bit contrived, though. Wondering if there were a more generally applicable solution.

Comment: Have you dumped `dset.info`, to see if it says where it came from? [I have no idea if it does, but I would think it would be part of `info`, if its anywhere.].

Answer (score 4):

You can get the path to the original file from an open dataset or dataarray with:

```
dset.encoding['source']
```

Comment: This depends on how the `Dataset` was constructed. In some cases the encoding may only be present on the `DataArray`s in `Dataset.data_vars`.